# how to use typed DataSets in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to google but didn't find a decent tutorial with snippet code.

Does anyone used typed DataSets\DataTable in c# ?

Is it from .net 3.5 and above?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=vs.71).aspx - this is the link to the .NET 1.1 version of the documentation, answering your second question...

Comment: They're an older technology, only use them when you have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has guidance.  It really hasn't changed since typed datasets were first introduced.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=VS.100).aspx

There are tons of videos available here: http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/series/aspdotnet_2_0_data_access_and_databinding/

And I found one more tutorial here: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031223.htm

Answer (score 4):

To answer the second parts of the question (not the "how to..." from the title, but the "does anyone..." and "is it...") - the answer would be a *yes*, but a *yes* with a pained expression on my face. For new code, I would strongly recommend looking at a class-based model; pick your poison between the many ORMs, micro-ORMs, and raw ADO.NET. `DataTable` itself *does* still have a use, in particular for processing and storing **unpredictable** data (where you have no idea what the schema is in advance). By the time you are talking about *typed* data-sets, I would suggest you obviously know enough about the type that this no longer applies, and an object-model is a very valid alternative.

It is still a supported part of the framework, and it is still in use as a technology. It has some nice features like the diff-set. However, most (if not all) of that is also available against an object-based design, with classes and properties (without the added overhead of the `DataTable` abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

Sparingly.... Unless you need to know to maintain legacy software, learn an ORM or two, particularly in conjunction with LINQ.
Some of my colleagues have them, the software I work on doesn't use them at all, on account of some big mouth developer getting his way again...

Comment: I wish I could have an example of a very big financial solution that deals with thoulsands of users and huge number of business validations / rules that is written in NHibernate / Entity Framework and that works decently. In my opinion, this is just a sweet dream.